# Where is the default maven-release-plugin defined?

Tags: java, maven

`mvn:effective-pom` claims my project uses

```
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
          </plugin>
```

but nowhere in the project I have this defined. I tried grepping in the project dir and in the apache-maven dir for "maven-release" but it didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: The best practices to always define all plugins you are using during your build...in a parent pom (corporate pom)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defined in one of the parent POMs, or in the [Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM), which is an implicit parent of every other POM.

Here's how the Super POM looks like for Maven version 3.3.9: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html

the relevant snippet:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the version is not defined in the  or  sections of your pom or parent pm. It will depend on the maven version you are using.

Comment: it's not defined in the project and it doesn't use a parent pom

Comment: You are alway using the super pom.. like in Java you always using Object